# I need to find the obtuse angle between the following two lines

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, geometry

I need to find the obtuse angle between two lines but I am not sure how to code it.

my two angles are +√3=1     and      (1−√3)+(1+√3)=8

I already did the calculations but im just not sure how to implement it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Specifically what I need is to convert the two equations to slope intercept form, and then use that slope in the formula
Theta = arctan m2- m1/ 1+ m1*m2

[image: calculations]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Are you seeking a Mathematica based solution? or a Math solution? For a math solution, please post at [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 2):

Why slope intercept form? From the equations we immediately know their normal vectors are `{1, Sqrt[3]}` and `{1 - Sqrt[3], 1 + Sqrt[3]}`, so the angle between the lines is

```
VectorAngle[{1, Sqrt[3]}, {1 - Sqrt[3], 1 + Sqrt[3]}] // Simplify
(* π/4 *)
```

You need a obtuse angle, so we simply do `π - π/4` and obtain `3 π/4`. The whole process can be automated with:

```
angle…between…lines[eqns_, vars_] := 
 VectorAngle @@ CoefficientArrays[eqns, vars][[-1]] // Simplify

obtuse = If[# > Pi/2, #, Pi - #] &;
acute  = If[# < Pi/2, #, Pi - #] &;
```

Then we can calculate the angle directly from the equation:

```
obtuse@angle…between…lines[{x + √3 y == 1, (1 - √3) x + (1 + √3) y == 8}, {x, y}]
(* (3 π)/4 *)
```

If you need acute angle, use `acute` instead of `obtuse` in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Or `Differences` the two points on the line to get the direction of line.

```
eqn1 = x + Sqrt[3] y == 1;
eqn2 = (1 - Sqrt[3]) x + (1 + Sqrt[3]) y == 8;
dir1 = {x, y} /. FindInstance[eqn1, {x, y}, Reals, 2] // 
   Differences;
dir2 = {x, y} /. FindInstance[eqn2, {x, y}, Reals, 2] // 
   Differences;
angle = VectorAngle[dir1[[1]], dir2[[1]]] // FullSimplify
Max[angle, π - angle]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, is there any way I can get it into the exact radian measurement? and it rounded to 3 decimal places?